# Why does Webpack encounter an error on an Express.js generated project?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, express-generator

I am new to the Node community and trying to start up a node (v6.1.0) project.

#### Setup

1. I set up a project using the Express generator.  It creates a `/bin/www`, which seems to require the `app.js` in the root directory and then spin up a  server.
2. I try to set up Webpack (1.13.1) in two ways either by setting my npm start script to `webpack --watch /bin/www bundle.js` in package.json, or by setting the entry and output in the webpack.config.js as per the docs.

#### Error 1

It doesn't matter which config I try to use (I only use one at a time), I get an error message when I start my webpack:

> ERROR in ./bin/www
>   Module parse failed: ~/testproject/bin/www Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

That line is `#!/usr/bin/env node`, which I would think shouldn't cause an error.

#### Error 2

If I comment out that line (which I didn't think I should have to).  It kind of looks like the bundle builds, but then there's a whole host of other errors:

> ERROR in ./~/serve-favicon/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in ... 
>   ERROR in ./~/etag/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in ...
>   ERROR in ./~/express/lib/request.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in ...

---

All of this looks kind of foreign to me.

1. I'm looking for a simple way to set up the scaffolding and run Webpack (and eventually Babel/React), but I can't even get past the setup/startup
2. I've searched the Googles, YouTubes and Webpack/Express documentation; but there doesn't seem to be a good example (or explanation) of how to use Webpack with Express generator.  Can anyone explain?
3. There doesn't seem to be much information about the two together, except to use Webpack with React and then require the Express at some point (I'm not quite sure why), but the file structures are different from using the Express generator. Can anyone provide a helpful site?  These are not enough:

   - http://blog.mixtape.press/using-webpack-with-express-js-react-js/
   - https://blog.risingstack.com/using-react-with-webpack-tutorial/

Comment: Express and webpack are separate. Webpack just generate the bundle which you will include in script tag on the index.html served by one of many possible webserver such as express.

Comment: Learn the technology sepaaretely before you combine, make a simple static webpage with express, add react to it, then bundle the react project w/ webpack https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto

Comment: Okay, I understand they are separate, but after I run `express testproject` (as per http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), then I try to set up webpack (as per https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html), I encounter the errors listed above.  What should my webpack entry point be on a brand new express install?

Comment: @aarosil I am trying to learn it!  This is a vanilla project.  That's the whole point.  I'm missing something simple.  I ran the page, I edited a page it was easy to just do `... npm start`, now I tried to add webpack in (as recommended), how much more basic can I get?

Comment: You need to make a new entry point, then make a index.html, include the bundle.js on that index.html, and configure express to serve that index.html (you can use express static module). Basically right now you're trying to use server start script as the webpack entry point, it could never work.

Comment: I'll add I've done other Node tutorial that were just for React, which work.  This is to get webpack to work and it's not packing a freshly generated project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114905/discussion-between-armando-and-aarosil).

Comment: Basically make a new file index.js and use that as entry point for webpack. then take bundle.js what webpack created, incude on script tag inside the index.html served by express server.

Answer (score 0):

As per the conversation with @aarosil, I've learned that the webpack tutorial I was following was poorly written for new entrants to webpack.  It suggested setting the package.json:start script with the webpack run script, replacing the `/bin/www`, making it seem that `/bin/www` was the entry point.  That is not correct.

It also made it seem that webpack could be pointed to any top level JS file and sniff and package together the client side JavaScript, which made me think it knew how to skip over the Server/Router portions.  This also was not correct.

Webpack is solely used for client side JavaScript.  If using the Express scaffolding, which handles the routing and uses jade templates for different views, if those Jade templates don't share JavaScript, they have different entry points.  Each entry point would have to webpacked (bundled) and the bundle included in the jade template (or however it can be inserted into the HTML document), but the easiest way would be to update the jade template.

Comment: @aarosil Wouldn't blame you if you wouldn't want to continue this discussion, but I'm now curious why it wouldn't be possible to webpack the node server entry (/bin/www), shouldn't that be able to traverse the backend JavaScript and create a backendbundle which I should be able to `node backendbundle.js`, provided I somehow exclude the "/node_modules" directory?